# Find current date (require for wishing happy birthday)

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I want to select current system date from a table of DOB(date of birth) in member_info table

```
DESIGNATION                             DOB       GENDER   MARITAL_STATUS
STUDENT                             4-Jun-1996      MALE         SINGLE
BUSINESS OWNER                      13-Sep-1981     MALE         MARRIED
BUSINESS OWNER                      1-Jan-1959      MALE         MARRIED
```

Comment: Do you mean the most recent date among the dates available ?

Comment: MySQL and/or Oracle? (Date/time is one of the areas where too many dbms products aren't standard compliant.)

Comment: "Please reply quickly"?  This site is run by volunteers.  You have no SLA with us.  So it's pretty cheeky to demand a snappy response.

Comment: i repeat my question   i have a table of member_info in which i want two columns records first DOB and second contact No      i want to wish happy birthday whose data of birth (DOB) is match with system date means current date

Comment: And I repeat my question, have you managed to find out if your using MySQL or Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

In **Oracle**, you could use **SYSDATE** to compare the **date and month** with **TO_CHAR** and proper format.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH dates AS(
  2  SELECT 'Mark' names,  to_date('4-Jun-1996', 'DD-Mon-YYYY') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'Henry' names, to_date('7-Apr-1981', 'DD-Mon-YYYY') dt FROM dual
  4  )
  5  SELECT names,
  6    CASE
  7      WHEN TO_CHAR(dt, 'MM/DD') = TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'MM/DD')
  8      THEN 'Happy Birthday'
  9      ELSE 'Not today'
 10    END is_bday_today
 11  FROM dates;

NAMES IS_BDAY_TODAY
----- --------------
Mark  Not today
Henry Happy Birthday

SQL>
```